# Is there any way to reset the rotation flag of videos while using concat to combine them?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, python

as title. I'm working on an un-chaptering script through the ffmpeg python library, and I've set up a very basic script for concat'ing several files. this is currently what I have:

```
if (os.path.isfile(i)):
        continue
    with open('merge_list.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join([f"""file '{path}\{x}'""" for x in filelist[i]]))
    
    ffmpeg.input('merge_list.txt', format='concat', safe=False).output(i, c='copy').run()
```

this works perfectly fine, without any hitches, but I've found that somehow, through this concat operation, the rotation flag is somehow still kept (why does this even happen? what if one out the two videos had a rotation flag, which flag would be kept for the final video?). either way, I'm hoping to either reset the rotation flag of the final or reset the rotation flag of the individual videos. I'm mostly trying to see if this can be done in one operation, and not two; is this possible?

thanks!

Comment: Try adding `-metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0` after the `-c copy`. The Python syntax is `ffmpeg.input('merge_list.txt', format='concat', safe=False).output('concatenated.mp4', c='copy', **{'metadata:s:v:0': 'rotate=0'}).run()`.

Comment: this is awesome!! thanks so much! I was just wondering a real quick question; would it be possible to fully remove the flag like a normally un-rotated video would be or is the only way to reset the flag to simply set it to 0? (also you should make an answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removing the rotation metadata, add `-metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0` after `-c copy`.

The Python syntax is:

`ffmpeg.input('merge_list.txt', format='concat', safe=False).output('concatenated.mp4', c='copy', **{'metadata:s:v:0': 'rotate=0'}).run()`

Note: Setting `rotate=0` is same as removing the rotation metadata.

---

Testing:

Creating 3 synthetic patterns, `vid2.mp4` is marked as rotated by 90 degrees:

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=192x108:r=1:d=5 vid1.mp4`
`ffmpeg -y -i vid1.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 vid2.mp4`
`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=192x108:r=1:d=5 vid3.mp4`

Create `merge_list.txt` file with the following content:

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file vid2.mp4
file vid1.mp4
file vid3.mp4
```

Note: By default FFmpeg copy the rotation metadata from the first file.

Concatenating the files without setting `rotate=0`:

`ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i merge_list.txt -c copy merged.mp4`

`merged.mp4` video is played rotated by 90 degrees:
[image]

Same command with `rotate=0`:

`ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i merge_list.txt -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 merged2.mp4`

`merged2.mp4` video is played without rotation:
[image]

Comment: this is INCREDIBLE, thanks so much!!